# Sumar registros por meses

Tags: laravel, eloquent, querybuilder

Ayudar por favor, estoy utilizando laravel con postgres, en la cual tengo una tabla llamada CAMPANIA, en mi consulta puedo sumar registros por meses y segun el tipo de campania en los meses que si existen registros, pero deseo obtener tambien los meses que no tienen registros. Talves alguien tiene alguna idea como lo puedo realizar con eloquent o Query Builder o de alguna otra forma.

```
public static function campaniasUnidosSomosMas(){
        return Campania::select('campanias.tipo_contribucion_campania_id as tipo_campania',DB::raw('count(campanias.tipo_contribucion_campania_id) as total_campania' ),DB::raw("extract(year from created_at) as year"), DB::raw("extract(month from created_at) as mes"))
                            ->groupBy('mes','year','campanias.tipo_contribucion_campania_id')
                            ->orderBy('mes', 'ASC')
                            ->get();

        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Deseo poder obtener resultados de la consulta de esta forma tambien
{"tipo_campania":1,"total_campania":"0","year":"2019","mes":"3"}

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [ask], nos muestras que has intentado?

Comment: Muchas gracias por la recomendacion

Comment: los códigos van como texto, una vez hecho eso seleccionalo y realiza la combinación de teclas `ctrl + k`